# Extending MvcAjaxResponse (wrap result) for web API with new fields

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Is there a way to add extra fields to wrapped response for every API call? I would like to add field "databaseVersion" in my response wrapper like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": {
    ... 
  },
  "error": null,
  "targetUrl": null,
  "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
  "__abp": true,
  "databaseVersion" : 5.2
}
```

Is there a simple way to do that without creating completely new logic for wrapping response? I am using latest asp.net core 2.X SPA template.

Comment: Yes it is. @AlperEbicoglu helped me a lot with his answer. It is a bit late now so I will post complete solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using an old version of ABP. Because I don't see MvcAjaxResponse in the current version.

To give you some clues, there are multiple ajax responses but they all implement [IAbpActionResultWrapper](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/f10fa5205c780bcc27adfe38aaae631f412eb7df/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Mvc/Results/Wrapping/AbpJsonActionResultWrapper.cs). If you implement your own [IAbpActionResultWrapper](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/f10fa5205c780bcc27adfe38aaae631f412eb7df/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Mvc/Results/Wrapping/AbpJsonActionResultWrapper.cs) then you can add custom properties.

```cs
public class AbpJsonActionResultWrapper : IAbpActionResultWrapper
{
    public void Wrap(ResultExecutingContext actionResult)
    {
        var jsonResult = actionResult.Result as JsonResult;
        if (jsonResult == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(actionResult)} should be JsonResult!");
        }

        if (!(jsonResult.Value is AjaxResponseBase))
        {
            jsonResult.Value = new AjaxResponse(jsonResult.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

See [AbpActionResultWrapperFactory](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/90b00d01333361eb19953ea0caf2bc6a41acccde/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Mvc/Results/Wrapping/AbpActionResultWrapperFactory.cs), it's where the concrete object is being created.

```cs
public IAbpActionResultWrapper CreateFor(ResultExecutingContext actionResult)
{
    Check.NotNull(actionResult, nameof(actionResult));

    if (actionResult.Result is ObjectResult)
    {
        return new AbpObjectActionResultWrapper(actionResult.HttpContext.RequestServices);
    }

    if (actionResult.Result is JsonResult)
    {
        return new AbpJsonActionResultWrapper();
    }

    if (actionResult.Result is EmptyResult)
    {
        return new AbpEmptyActionResultWrapper();
    }

    return new NullAbpActionResultWrapper();
}
```